# Yii dropdown different display values

Tags: yii

What is the best way to display 1 as "Yes" and 0 as "No" on View and listing pages which use Yii generated CRUD code (`zii.widgets.CDetailView`).

I'm writing down below simply which worked for me if it helps others (Thanks to Pentium 10 for the hint):

### BEFORE: (Generated by Gii)

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        's_no',
        'gateway',
        'code',
        'isvlid',
    ),
));
```

### AFTER: (Manually edited slightly)

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        's_no',
        'gateway',
        'code',

    // Is Valid (Now i control the Label and Display Value)
        array(
      'label'=>'Active',
      'value'=>$model->isvalid ? "Yes" : "No",
    ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this a CGridView, it might help you:

```
array(
    'name' => 'isregistered',
    'header' => "Reg.?",
    'value' => '$data->isregistered?Yii::t(\'app\',\'Yes\'):Yii::t(\'app\', \'No\')',
    'filter' => array('0' => Yii::t('app', 'No'), '1' => Yii::t('app', 'Yes')),
    'htmlOptions' => array('style' => "text-align:center;"),
),
```

Comment: I used the label and value and it works, thanks.

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
 'data'=>$model,
 'attributes'=>array(
  's_no',
  'gateway',
  'code',

    // Is Valid
  array(
      'label'=>'Active',
      'value'=>$model->isvalid ? "Yes" : "No",
    ),
 ),
)); ?>

Comment: Man, do you know how to do the same for index listing page i.e. in cListView Widget. What do i need to change in this views/index.php:

    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
 'itemView'=>'_view',
    )); ?>

Comment: You change the _view file in that case. It's up to you there how you print the values.